# Highlighting A Row Based On Current Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, highlight

I have a spreadsheet in which each row of column F has a specific date. I want the sheet to highlight the row which corresponds to the current date (today). Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the conditional formatting formula:

```
=$F1=Today()
```

and apply to the range, say,

```
=$A$1:$F$10
```

[image]

Note: Using `TODAY()` means that when you open the sheet tomorrow, or any other day, it's going to see if the cell is equal to that day.  To make it literally today, you can do:

```
=$F1=DATE(2018,01,25)
```